# dispatch ACTION_CANCEL without onInterceptTouchEvent

Tags: android, motionevent

I am extending View and overriding onTouchEvent.
I want to fire/dispatch MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL when the second finger touch the screen.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either call or override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event).

Who do you want to send ACTION_CANCEL to?  If your View is a ViewGroup for instance, this would send it to all of its children on the second press:

```
class MyGroup extends ViewGroup {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Is this the second finger down?
        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            // Cancel all children
            MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
            cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                child.dispatchTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
            }
            cancelEvent.recycle();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise just do the normal behavior
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your code does fire the event, thanks. But firing the ACTION_CANCEL doesn't seem useful as I think it would.

I just want my custom View dispatch ACTION_CANCEL when the second finger come, in hope another custom View below it handle the multi touch. But it doesn't happen that way. It feels like the fingers  stuck on the first (top) custom View.